# How do I update a cell based on a triggered event using a formula?

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

My end goal is have the Power SQL query refresh A2 each minute.
After each update occurs in A2 the macro should compare the value in A2 with the value in B2.

```
IF A2 > B2 Then B2 = A2 Else B2 = B2
```

Here's what I have tried to hobble together... most of the SO articles all show how to display a message box, but I need a cell to update.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    DoEvents

    With Range("B2")
        .Value = .Value
        DoEvents
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$2" And Range("A2").Value > Range("B2").Value Then
        Range("B2").Value = Range("A2").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Please help! I am able to get message boxes to populate when the value changes, but not get the cell B2 to update if A2 > B2.

Thanks,

PP

[image: View of excel sheet with data populating A2]

Comment: isn't that initial `Application.EnableEvents = False` preventing any triggering of `Worksheet_Change()` event?

Comment: @DisplayName trying that now. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your code with this

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.Range("B2").Value2 = Me.Range("B2").Value2
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Val(Me.Range("A2")) > Val(Me.Range("B2")) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("B2") = Me.Range("A2")
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

To place a break point click the gray bar on the left, as in the image bellow

[image: PlaceABreakPoint]

Comment: Hey @paul thanks for the response! I need some clarification.

So do I keep the top part?  Also I am super noob with VBA and just have the worksheet level code. I don't have modules or anything not sure if that would be needed.if this is how it should look it throws an error.  The "Option Explicit" parts shows up under the first sub. Error: "only comments may appear after end sub, end function, or end property.

Comment: Sorry to clarify further - I had two sub initially. When I pasted the code into the second sub to replace it, it puts the Option Explicit into the 1st sub and throws and error.

Comment: it no longer throws a compile error. I saved the code. Saved the excel book. Closed excel and reopened. The value in A2 updated upon refresh but the value in B2 stayed at zero.

Maybe I am missing something at the macro level or module level?

Comment: Okay so the code works if I manually change the Value in A2, but it doesn't work if the query runs and updates the A2 value or if I manually refresh it.

Comment: Code change compiled, but same results. The value in A2 and was > than B2, but B2 didn't update.

To test I set both values in A2 and B2 = 12.  Then ran a refresh to trigger the query. A2 updated to 32, but B2 stayed at 12.

Comment: I made another change. Can you place a break point in `Worksheet_Calculate()` on line `Me.Range("B2").Value2 = Me.Range("B2").Value2`. If the code execution stops there when you trigger the refresh please press `F8` to see where the next line of execution will jump